# Update the result of a SELECT statement in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a complicated select statement, for example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Orders] a 
INNER JOIN [Customers] b ON a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%Wilman%'
```

This gives me the row(s) I need, I then want to be able to `UPDATE` the row(s) almost like this:

```
UPDATE ([Orders] a 
INNER JOIN [Customers] b ON a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%Wilman%') 
SET ShipperID = 10
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but who I get that type of logic to work in Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: I mean no disrespect, but I lost it at *complicated*. Thats about the least complicated query one could write.

Comment: @Jamiec that is not the actual database I am working with, and that is not the actually query I am working with. I substituted everything in the post with more simple examples so the answers are more general to people reading this in the future, and to keep irrelevant information out of my question.

Answer (score 2):

it must be :

```
UPDATE
    Orders
SET
    ShipperID = 10
FROM
    [Orders] a INNER JOIN [Customers] b on a.CustomerID=b.CustomerID   
WHERE
    CustomerName LIKE '%Wilman%
```

Comment: Let's say I wanted to SET two different values, for examples: `ShipperId = 10 AND Address = 'Long Distance' how would I do that?

Comment: You should actually "Update a" and not the base table. There are some times when sql can get confused and update incorrect rows.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the `SELECT` statement returns unique column names and meets the criteria for updatable views you can just chuck it into a derived table or CTE and update that.

```
UPDATE (SELECT a.ShipperID
        FROM   [Orders] a
               INNER JOIN [Customers] b
                 ON a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
        WHERE  CustomerName LIKE '%Wilman%') AS T
SET    ShipperID = 10
```

Comment: Good to know about this

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to `UPDATE/FROM`

```
UPDATE o
SET ShipperID = 10
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN Customers c ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
WHERE c.CustomerName LIKE '%Wilman%'
```

Comment: I gave that a try on `http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all`  which is where I am testing the script on (I don't want to mess up my actual database) it is giving me an error near `FROM`. Is `FROM` a SQL Server operation?

Comment: @iamtesla "W3Schools has created an SQL database in your browser." - That isn't going to be SQL Server as tagged then.

Comment: @Jamiec For SQL Server (tagged) you are able to update an aliased table. I have several processes doing that currently.

Comment: @MartinSmith my apologies, I tried to keep the example in the question simple. The actual database I am working on is in SQL Server. I just use the site as a simple test area.

Comment: @iamtesla -  So use SQL Fiddle instead as that has SQL Server backend.

Comment: @Phoenix - yep I went and checked after posting that comment. My bad, should have checked first ;)

Comment: @MartinSmith Thank you! Much better than what I was using. Its my first week on the job and I've never done much SQL stuff. Thanks again. Great link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [common table expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms190766). Assuming `ShipperID` is a column of `Orders` and assuming `CustomerName` is a column of `Customers` (it is, incidentally, best practice to always prefix your columns in a `JOIN` to prevent surprises with future schema changes):

```
WITH OrdersToUpdate AS (
    SELECT [Orders].*
    FROM [Orders]
    INNER JOIN [Customers] ON [Orders].CustomerID = [Customers].CustomerID
    WHERE [Customers].CustomerName LIKE '%Wilman%'
)
UPDATE OrdersToUpdate SET ShipperID = 10;
```

This technique is especially useful because it allows you to see what will be updated (or deleted if you use `DELETE`) without rewriting your query.